# JQuery select text from anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i've building a nodejs app and using jquery in it. I try to get the text from a anchor from an nested list:

```
<ul class="someClass">
  <li>
    <a href="/blabla">Anchor Content</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My JQuery Code to get the content is:

```
$('#someClass').find('a').text();
```

Unfortunately it isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: `#` is for `id`. `.` is for `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$('.someClass').find('a').text();
```

Use the class selector. Until now, you're just using the ID selector. In jQuery `.` is the class selector. In HTML you're using the class not the ID. So that code won't work.

For more on jQuery selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/